# How to get the function located at a memory address in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I am trying to get the function located at a particular address in a dll.

I have tried viewing the disassembly of the dll but there are no debugging symbols.

```
auto lib = LoadLibrary("lib.dll");
auto proc = GetProcAddress(lib, "proc1"); // Getting the address of the function.
```

How do I get "proc1" (the function name) back from proc (the address) without calling GetProcAddress for every function in the dll? There does not seem to be a function for this purpose. Is there any other way to get the function name?

Comment: get dll wich containing this address, then enumerate all dll exports and select functions, which address match

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: first call `RtlPcToFileHeader` then enumerate dll export

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. I can't find any good documentation for `RtlPcToFileHeader`. Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: It should be noted that more than one function name can resolve to a specific address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the list of functions inside the DLL, it's possible to use a tool.
http://www.dependencywalker.com/

But i'm not sure to understand why you need to do that at runtime. Most of the time the function you need to use from a DLL you already know the name and parameters and have already a header ready to interact with it.

But if you realy need to do the reverse process check that open source project, you might find inside the source code what you need. It's in C# but might gives you some hints.
https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Comment: It doesn't need to be at runtime. Dependency Walker worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

first of all we need found the base address of the image that contains the specified memory address. this can be done by [`RtlPcToFileHeader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/nf-winnt-rtlpctofileheader) function.

then we need get it export directory via say [`ImageDirectoryEntryToData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-imagedirectoryentrytodata) from *Dbghelp.dll* or via `RtlImageDirectoryEntryToData` from *ntdll.dll* and enumerate all exportfuntions. first look by name. if no name for such address - look ordinal.

```
void FromAddress(LPCVOID Address)
{
    PVOID BaseOfImage = RtlPcToFileHeader(Address, &BaseOfImage);

    if (!BaseOfImage)
    {
        return;
    }

    ULONG Size;
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY pied = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)
    RtlImageDirectoryEntryToData(BaseOfImage, TRUE, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT, &Size);

    ULONG NumberOfFunctions, NumberOfNames;

    if (!pied || !(NumberOfFunctions = pied->NumberOfFunctions))
    {
        return;
    }

    NumberOfNames = pied->NumberOfNames;

    PULONG AddressOfFunctions = (PULONG)RtlOffsetToPointer(BaseOfImage, pied->AddressOfFunctions);
    PULONG AddressOfNames = (PULONG)RtlOffsetToPointer(BaseOfImage, pied->AddressOfNames); 
    PUSHORT AddressOfNameOrdinals = (PUSHORT)RtlOffsetToPointer(BaseOfImage, pied->AddressOfNameOrdinals);

    bool bFound = false;

    if (NumberOfNames)
    {
        do 
        {
            ULONG rva = *AddressOfNames++;

            if (RtlOffsetToPointer(BaseOfImage, AddressOfFunctions[*AddressOfNameOrdinals++]) == Address)
            {
                DbgPrint("%s\n", RtlOffsetToPointer(BaseOfImage, rva));
                bFound = true;
            }
        } while (--NumberOfNames);
    }

    if (!bFound)
    {
        DWORD Base = pied->Base;

        do 
        {
            if (Address == RtlOffsetToPointer(BaseOfImage, *AddressOfFunctions++))
            {
                DbgPrint("#%u\n", Base);
            }
        } while (Base++, --NumberOfFunctions);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not get that to compile.

Comment: @me' - and so what ?

Comment: `RtlOffsetToPointer` is not defined.

Comment: @me' - `RtlOffsetToPointer` defined in *Ntifs.h*, you can easy found this in google. you not include *ntifs.h* unlike me. but no problem copy-paste or use equal by sense definition - `RtlOffsetToPointer(B,O)  ((PCHAR)( ((PCHAR)(B)) + ((ULONG_PTR)(O))  ))`

Comment: Using `((PCHAR)( ((PCHAR)(B)) + ((ULONG_PTR)(O)) ))`, `ImageDirectoryEntryToData` rather than `RtlImageDirectoryEntryToData` and stdout instead of `DbgPrint`, this works. I don't think I have the driver kit required for those.